# Issue with field disappearing when refresh

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a field called IP Restriction and when you load the page first time, it shows up without issue. However when I refresh the page it disappears and only will show up again if I exist out of the page to and return back to it. All other fields are fine except this so I'm wondering what might the issue be.

HTML:

```html
<div class="widget-body">
  <form class="form-horizontal" name="siteUserDetailsForm">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 control-label no-padding-right">Site Name</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" ng-if="isNewSiteUser">
          <select ng-options="siteName.id as siteName.title for siteName in clientSiteNameList" id="siteName" ng-model="targetEntity.siteId" ng-change="onSiteNameChange()">
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" ng-if="!isNewSiteUser">
          <select disabled>
            <option value="">{{targetEntity.siteName}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 control-label no-padding-right">IP Restrictions</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
          <tags-input use-strings="true" id="ipRestrictions" ng-model="targetEntity.ipRestrictions" ng-disabled="editMode == false" placeholder="Add new host or IP">
          </tags-input>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nonBillable" class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 control-label no-padding-right">Non-billable?</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
          <label class="checkbox-top-pad">
            <input id="nonBillable" class="checkbox-slider yesno" type="checkbox"
              ng-model="targetEntity.nonBillable"
              ng-disabled="editMode == false">
            <span class="text"></span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="concurrentAccessCount" class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 control-label no-padding-right">Concurrent Access Count</label>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
          <div class="input-group spinner">
            <input id="concurrentAccessCount" type="number" min="1" class="form-control" ng-model="targetEntity.concurrentAccessCount" ng-disabled="editMode == false">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : siteUserDetailsForm.site.$invalid && !siteUserDetailsForm.site.$pristine }">
        <label for="entitleOnDemand" class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 control-label no-padding-right">Entitlements On Demand</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
          <select ng-options="entitlementSet.id as entitlementSet.name for entitlementSet in entitlementSetList" id="entitleOnDemand" ng-disabled="editMode == false" ng-model="targetEntity.entitlementsOnDemandId">
            <option value=""> -- Please Select --</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Visual guide

[image]

Comment: apparently this has nothing to do with your HTML, otherwise this coulve been reproduced in your fiddle, but the field is always showing

Comment: is this really an Angular question in disguise? if so, update your question with the typescript file and html of the component

Comment: Sorry, wasn't too sure it was an AngularJS issue. Will update with angularJS code.